# How can I do an in-place union within a subclass of set without iterating through all the things I want to add (again)?

Tags: python, set

### Background

I'm just doing an exercise following a course (pyt201 at FXPHD if anyone was curious) and one of the things we're building up is a SequentialRange class that's meant to represent frames of footage. For simplicity assume integer frame numbers and no weird sub-frame renders.

One method i'm implementing is `add_frames(self, *frames)` which accepts an unspecified lot of iterables and adds them in. The demo code simply does this:

```
for frame in imap(int, chain(*frames)):
        self.add(frame)
```

### I'd like to..

...avoid this behaviour since if you pass in a malformed sequence (say, trivially, [1,2,"fish",6,7]) your resulting SequentialRange will be in one of those ugly half-processed states which helps nobody. Since it's a set I know you could just patch the input, and readd it and dupes will be thrown out but I'd like to write it up so that the add_frames() operation is more binary and either successfully loads all the frames, OR doesn't pollute the existing set.

The thought process was that basically, I'll have an `add_frame()` method which I'll do any mystical voodoo necessary (right now it's just `self.add(int(the_input_frame_value))`) which in a way provides me my sanity check on the input. So I can create a temporary set from the input, and if that's successful, do a union of the temp set and the original set. The problem I'm finding is that union returns me a copy made up of the union of the two sets, so I have to resort to something like:

```
temporary_set = SequentialRange()
try:
    for frame in itertools.chain(*frames):
        temporary_set.add_frame(frame)
except ValueError:
    # placeholder flameout message
    print("malformed input, no changes made")
    return
except:
    raise

for x in temporary_set:
    self.add_frame(x)
```

### It works but...

...I'm unconvinced that re-iterating through the set is a good idea. It feels, err.. wrong? Mainly I think because I've gone and iterated through my input once for sanity checking, I don't like having to reiterate for an add phase.

So yes, any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong? I can't shake the feeling that there's something I'm missing that would make this easier, but at the same time, since this is for the sheer learning heck of it, alt approaches to the problem also welcomed..

Comment: If you don't want a new set, maybe you want to use 'update' rather than 'union'?

Comment: *groan* oh ffs. Why the heck didn't I see that? I'm tempted to downvote my own question now :P Thanks!